# best way to group date in a range

Tags: sql, sql-server

Just wondering if I have two fields in a table named modified date and created date, they either have a date populate or is null. What I would like to know is the best way to count the number of occurrences and group them into a particular range like for example 0-7 days, 8-14 days, 15- 30 days etc.

I was thinking about using

```
sum(case when modifieddate between getdate()-7 and getdate() then 1 else 0 end)
```

Is this the best way to do it or is there a better way for each date range specified above. Same would go for the created date

Comment: If the ranges aren't uniform, then you could do something like the following to produce a list of ranges: `SELECT CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -R.startR, GETDATE()) AS DATE) startD, CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -R.endR, GETDATE()) AS DATE) endD FROM (VALUES (0, 7), (8, 14), (15, 30)) R(startR, endR)` then join it back to your original query. NOTE: there's a cast to date here, which can be tricky if your modified date is a DATETIME and not a DATE.

Comment: Thank you, its actually datetime, how would I tackle that problem

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired outcome

Comment: @abs786123 There are a few options. You could cast the modifieddate as a date if you want to just take everything on a given day. Or if you actually want to get it down to the time, then you need to decide what you want to do, for example, what should happen at 7.5 days (not between 0-7 or 8-14) and if instead you want 0-7, 7-14 then what should happen in the case of an overlap (at 7).

Comment: your question appear to be interesting.care to explain more.you mean to say tat you will always compare it with current date,such that records that is currently in "0-7 days",tomorrow it may in "8-14 days" group and so on.
Create table or CTE which contain 2 columns daydiff and Groupname.
Then in another CTE,only find datediff,then finally join this two cte.

Answer (score 0):

Build a table containing the ranges on the fly, then access your table and count:

```
select
  mindays, 
  maxdays,
  (
    select count(*)
    from mytable t 
    where datediff(day, coalesce(t.modifieddate, t.createddate), getdate() )
            between ranges.mindays and ranges.maxdays
  ) as cnt
from
(
  select 0 as mindays, 7 as maxdays
  union all
  select 8 as mindays, 14 as maxdays
  union all
  select 15 as mindays, 30 as maxdays
) ranges;
```